# setup ssh private/public keys

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption

I have done the following:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then put the contents of the id_rsa.pub into the remote ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. I thought that should do it. But it still prompts for a password. Not the id_rsa password...I did a ssh-add which that is all set but the computer password (remote password) in order to log into the remote system. I specify a User in my .ssh/config file so it knows what user to use.

I checked my remote .ssh directory and it is 700. The only thing I can think of is the .ssh directory is owned by john. When I connect to the remote system I do john@ip and the computer that I am connecting with (local machine) the username is johnsmith. Could that be why? If so, is there a way I can allow this without having to make the same user for each system?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Apparently the permissions for the file `authorized_keys` on the remote server needed to be set: `chmod 700`.